# Compactness already if every open cover of subbasis elements has a finite subcover?

Tags: general-topology, lattice-orders

Let $X$ be a topological space, and let $\mathcal V$ be a basis.

If I want to prove that $X$ is compact then it is clear to me that it is enough to prove that every open cover of elements of $\mathcal V$ has a finite subcover.

My question is:

> Is this also the case if $\mathcal V$ is not a basis but is a subbasis?

I really don't see that.

Further I am motivated to ask this by a proof that I met [here](http://sierra.nmsu.edu/morandi/notes/Duality.pdf) (lemma 3.1 page 6).

It shows that the set of prime filters of a bounded distributive lattice equipped with the topology generated by the collection $\{\phi(a)\mid a\in L\}\cup\{\phi(b)^{\complement}\mid b\in L\}$  is compact. Here $L$ denotes the lattice and $\phi(a)$ is the set of prime filters that contain $a$ as element (see definition 1.3). Further it is evident that the set $\{\phi(a)\cap\phi(b)^{\complement}\mid a,b\in L\}$ serves as basis of the topology.

The proof starts by saying that it is enough to prove it for covers of "basic sets" (so far I agree), but then only gives a proof for a cover of sets that come from the subbasis. This puzzles me.

If the answer to my posed question is "no" then another question:

> Is the proof that I quoted okay?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subbase#Alexander_subbase_theorem

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Thank you very much!! Actually I am a bit astonished that such a nice result never reached me before. I have not digested it yet, but will set my teeth in it.